# How would I make projectiles rain from the sky infinitely in Unity2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently trying to make a simple game in Unity where the player can move and dodge falling projectiles randomly. However, I am not totally sure how to implement something like this into my game.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The easiest way it's use Unity Particle System. For example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xkB6yzCBfgw

Comment: Is there any way to make the projectiles collide with the player and have it count damage? Sorry if my question was kind of unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a rain prefab with the tag such as "rain" and instantiate it at a random position. The problem with this is if you want a lot of raindrops this will be very slow, but you could make the raindrops near the player the prefab I was talking about and all the raindrops the player is unable to touch particles to give the illusion of acid rain.

Just an idea not sure how good this solution is, hope it helps!